# Business days between two dates in standard SQL using business days table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

this is a long shot, but I hope one of you wizards out there can help me.

My organization keeps calendar table, CalendarDays, that contains two columns, Date and IsBizDay which is boolean.

I would like to leverage this table to calculate the business days between another table,Contracts, which contains two columns; StartDate and EndDate.

My desired output would be StartDate,EndDate,BizDaysBetween.

Comment: Has `Contracts` a pk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select c.StartDate,
       c.EndDate,
       (select count(*)
        from CalandarDays d
        where d.Date >= c.StartDate
          and d.Date <  c.EndDate
          and d.IsBizDay
       ) as BizDaysBetween
from Contracts c
```

Comment: *Facepalm* Yes, of course. Thank you for the speedy and accurate answer

Answer (score 0):

Let's supose `pk` is the primary key for `Contracts` (or a unique field or field set). Then, the query you are looking for, without correlated subqueries, is:

```
select C.pk, C.StartDate, C.EndDate,
       Coalesce( Count(d.Date), 0 ) as BizDaysBetween
  from Contracts C
  left outer join CalandarDays d
          on d.Date >= c.StartDate
         and d.Date <  c.EndDate
         and d.IsBizDay
 group by C.pk, C.StartDate, C.EndDate
```

**Why a join instead a correlated subquery?**

Quoting [Wikipedia's Correlated subquery article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

> In a SQL database query, a correlated subquery (also known as a synchronized subquery) is a subquery (a query nested inside another query) that uses values from the outer query. Because the subquery may be evaluated once for each row processed by the outer query, **it can be inefficient.**

Remember to create right indexes. For `CalandarDays` the index may be composed by `(IsBizDay, Date)`.

**Why left join and coalesce?**

Because, may be, they are not any business day on range.

Comment: Brilliant - I appreciate the alternative solution to correlated subqueries and the included reasoning. On a very small dataset (54.2 KB), your solution is .1 second faster (2.0 vs 2.1 seconds). I can imagine how that would scale.